# Is this correct way to use cookies from a syntax point of view?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know if this is the right syntax for using cookies. I haven't yet tested this code with cookies being used.

I'm using a jQuery Plugin called [jPages](http://luis-almeida.github.com/jPages/) to display pages on my (one page) website, it has a lot of options and it's very flexible.

The jPages plugin has an option to start from a different page per say, and a callback function to find what page you are currently on.

I'm using `localStorage` to store the last page that a visitor has been on so that it can be retrieved when they return. I've tested this method and it works perfectly.

I'm using Modernizr to test for `localStorage` support in browsers, and if `localStorage` is not supported I use cookies to try and achieve the same experience.

Here's the part of my code that does that:

```
var set_data = function(cluster) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("Page")) {
        if (!localStorage.setItem("Page", JSON.stringify(cluster))) {
            log("Current Page: Stored");
        } else {
            log("Current Page: Store Failed");
        }
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("Page");
        if (!localStorage.setItem("Page", JSON.stringify(cluster))) {
            log("Current Page: Stored");
        } else {
            log("Current Page: Store Failed");
        }
    }
}

var get_data = function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("Page")) {
        var last_page = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Page"))
        log("Last Page: " + last_page);
        return last_page;
    } else {
        log("Last Page: Inexistent");
        return 1;
    }
}

var set_last_page = function(cluster) {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        var data = cluster;
        set_data(data);
    } else {
        var data = JSON.stringify(cluster);
        create_cookie("Page", data, 365);
    }
}

var get_current_page = function() {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        var data = get_data();
    } else {
        var data = JSON.parse(read_cookie("Page"));
    }
    return data;
}

var create_cookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var date;
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

var read_cookie = function(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    var i;
    var c;

    for (i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `localStorage` part works, but I'm not sure if I'm doing the cookie part correctly.

**If someone can tell me if this is the right syntax for using cookies, I would appreciate it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the expense of having a little more code, I would use a [localStorage polyfill](https://gist.github.com/2398893/d6327b3ca7b7c50d3f4f784e06bac76cf649fe0f) [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

With that code in place you no longer need to keep the create and read cookie methods. You also don't need the code wrapping `get_data` and `set_data`. Your resulting code would look something like this:

```
set_last_page = function(cluster) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("Page")) {
        if (!localStorage.setItem("Page", JSON.stringify(cluster))) {
            log("Current Page: Stored");
        } else {
            log("Current Page: Store Failed");
        }
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("Page");
        if (!localStorage.setItem("Page", JSON.stringify(cluster))) {
            log("Current Page: Stored");
        } else {
            log("Current Page: Store Failed");
        }
    }
}

get_current_page = function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("Page")) {
        var last_page = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Page"))
        log("Last Page: " + last_page);
        return last_page;
    } else {
        log("Last Page: Inexistent");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

From here I would make a few changes:

1. You don't need to check for existence or remove an item from storage to change it.
2. The logging code is unnecessary.
3. Using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` is considerable overkill for converting between a string and a number.

Taking care of these would leave me with this code:

```
set_last_page = function(cluster) {
    localStorage.setItem("Page", cluster+'');
}

get_current_page = function() {
    return +(localStorage.getItem("Page") || 1); 
    //localStorage.getItem("Page") will return either 
    // a number >= 1 (as a string), undefined or null 
    //so '|| 1' will take care of the latter cases
}
```

Finally, I dislike the fact you are initializing these variables as function expressions (statements) and don't end them with semicolons (either add the semis or make them function declarations). I would also rename things to be more consistent and in line with my preferred naming conventions for javascript:

```
function setPage(page) {
    localStorage.setItem('page', page+'');
}

function getPage() {
    return +(localStorage.getItem('page') || 1); 
}
```

Comment: I did not knew that the `localStorage` behaves the same way as cookies when it comes to overwrite, so this means I do not need to remove it each time I have a new values for it ? I'm doing the logging because I'm testing now and I like seeing in the console if there's something happening, after I'm done with the testing I remove all the console outputs. And about JSON, I've read that it's best to use it, as the polyfill does too. And I like having the variables as expressions rather than just simple functions :) But that's just me I guess. Thanks for the response, I appreciate it

Comment: Oh, so, if I use the polyfill, I'll end up using only those last two functions by your description, right ?

Comment: @Roland, correct (you only nee those last two functions, and it behaves the same way as cookies)